# Crystal Report do not do the sum on Database "Cache"

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report to do a sum over 3 columns.  The table structure looks like:

table #test (Country VARCHAR(10), Name VARCHAR(10), Weight VARCHAR(10), Qty INT)

I wrote a query in the crystal command pane when I do the connection:

SELECT Country, SUM(Qty) As Qty, Name, Weight FROM #test GROUP BY  Country, Name, Weight

I should get something like:

CANADA  2   John    200

US  1   John    160

US  2   Mike    180

US  6   Sam 90

However, the crystal report does not sum the field, instead it pulls every single row, and the result looks like I write the query:

SELECT Country, Qty, Name, Weight FROM #test

CANADA  1   John    200

CANADA  1   John    200

US  1   John    160

US  2   Mike    180

US  3   Sam 90

US  3   Sam 90

By the way, the backend database is called "Cache". It might be due to there are some hidden characters, but I cannot see them.  I have used replace (char(10)), replace (char(13) and trim to try to clean.

I also try to pull the table column directly without writing the query, but I do not know how to sum three columns (Country, Name and Weight).  I only know how to sum one column.  By the way, the request do not want the details, only the sum over these three columns;

Comment: Approach would be try to sum in crystal reports and dont take sum in command

Comment: Could you show me how to sum over three column please?

Answer (score 0):

1. First group by country.
2. Create one more group by quantity
3. Create one more group by name
4. Place weight in details and take the sum for all 3 groups if you need or only particular group
5. Supress tje details.